# getAdapterPosition returns -1 in ViewHolder class

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to show an `AlertDialog` in my `ViewHolder` class and after clicking on accept button I'm getting the Model item with `getAdapterPosition` from a list of items but in Fabric Crashlytics I have 13 crashes because of `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` which says length is 12 but the index requested is -1 and the crash is for `getPaymentMode` in this part of code

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView time, capacity, description;
    View button;
    ImageView avatar;

    ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        time = v.findViewById(R.id.reserve_times_time);
        capacity = v.findViewById(R.id.reserve_times_capacity);
        button = v.findViewById(R.id.button);
        description = v.findViewById(R.id.reserve_times_description);
        avatar = v.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                alertDialogBuilder.setView(R.layout.layout_dialog);
                alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("accept", null);
                alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("cancel", null);
                final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
                alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dialog_button_text_size));
                alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dialog_button_text_size));
                alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                        getPaymentMode(arrayList.get(getAdapterPosition()), button);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

in `RecyclerView` source code `getAdapterPosition` returns -1 when owner `RecyclerView` is null and that will happen if activity is closed but how this can be happened? when `AlertDialog` is displaying user can't close activity!

Comment: Post `ViewHolder` code

Comment: question edited @josh_gom3z

Comment: show your onbind method and where u setadapter

Comment: @Amir_P getAdapterPosition() is the position of item you  clicked right ?

Comment: that's right @Umair

Comment: it's only displaying image and text and I'm setting adapter after getting result from server @duggu

Comment: does your adapter support stable IDs (`RecyclerView.Adapter#hasStableIds()`)?

Comment: yes it supports but I'm using the default value(false) @pskink

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the error so how can I be sure this will fix the issue? @pskink

Comment: @Amir_P why don;t you use this clickListener in onBindViewHolder() method of your adapter. In this way you can get the position easily.

Comment: ok what you see if you `Log.d` the value of `ViewHolder.toString()`?

Comment: after setting `hasStableId` result of `Log.d` is always `ViewHolder{2612946 position=-1 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 unbound no parent}` @pskink

Comment: see [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/recyclerview/src/main/java/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.java#10753) for details, also what do you see if you `Log.d` the same before `alertDialog.show();` ?

Comment: I'm getting `ViewHolder{bf4f927 position=0 id=18585550, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1}` @pskink

Comment: so for some reason your view holder is unbound when alert is shown: just create a class that implements `OnClickListener` and pass the position in its constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getAdapterPosition()), `getAdapterPosition()` will return `NO_POSITION` (aka -1) if your view holder has already been recycled.

> The adapter position of the item if it still exists in the adapter. NO_POSITION if item has been removed from the adapter, notifyDataSetChanged() has been called after the last layout pass or the ViewHolder has already been recycled.

My guess is that by the time you're clicking on your dialog button, your view holder has already been recycled. Try to store the position right when your `onClick()` method begins and then use it when you need it, something like:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    final int position = getAdapterPosition()
    //Your code here             
    alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        alertDialog.dismiss();
        getPaymentMode(arrayList.get(position), button);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: is there any other side effects for this solution? Project has 20K+ users and I'm afraid this causes other problems

Comment: This is just an educated guess based on the code I'm able to see. By all means test it before using it in your production app, just like any other answer you see on Stack Overflow

Comment: With current code I'm not able to reproduce the error so It's hard to be sure but I will test it thanks