# Tab View Fragment not Refreshed after deleting item from Recyclerview and coming back to same Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, tabview

I have set up `Tabview` with 3 tabs using `Viewpager`.On second tab I have set up `Recyclerview`.After `onClick` on Recyclerview Item I am deleting that Item from Recyclerview using Recyclerview Aapter class and coming back to first tab.But when I scroll to second tab the item is not seen to be removed from Recyclerview.I need to manually again call the same Fragment of tabview and change is reflected.
This is code for deleting the item from Recyclerview.

```
 private void removeAtPosition(int adapterPosition) {
        entry.remove(adapterPosition);
        notifyItemRemoved(adapterPosition);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(adapterPosition,entry.size());
    }
```

This is code for Replacing the `Tabview` after item deletion.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //int position=getAdapterPosition();
        BusyEntry values=this.entry.get(getAdapterPosition());
        activity=(AppCompatActivity)v.getContext();
        final AlertDialog alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).create();
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        builder.setTitle("Confirmation");
        builder.setMessage("Do you really want to Free the Entry?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                String NetworkStatus= biz.fyra.bookapp.utils.NetworkStatus.checkConnection(activity);
                if(NetworkStatus.equals("false"))
                {
                    AlertClass alert=new AlertClass();
                    alert.noInternetAlert(activity);
                }
                else
                {
                    freeEntry();
                    String chooseTab="";
                    ChooseTab chooseTab1=new ChooseTab();
                    fm=activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
                    tx=fm.beginTransaction();
                    tx.replace(R.id.frame,chooseTab1,chooseTab);
                    removeAtPosition(getAdapterPosition());
                    BusyEntry entry=new BusyEntry();
                    tx.detach(entry);
                    tx.attach(entry);
                    tx.commit();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                alertDialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

How to handle this so that deleted item is instantly removed from Recyclerview and not visible after calling same Fragment.

Comment: may you debug what getAdapterPosition() returns? if result is -1 then check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48880846/getadapterposition-returns-1-in-viewholder-class

Comment: It returns the position of item I have clicked.

Comment: Did you debug or just indicate what it should do?

Comment: Yes I have debug.  I got  `I/position: 1` after clicking second item in recyclerview.